# How do you merge two HDRs in two layers in the same image?

Tags: photoshop, hdr, layers

I have two HDRs made by myself using two different photographs.

My problem comes when I open both in Photoshop: I cannot copy paste one over the other so I can mix them together. How can I do that?

Comment: File > Place...

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean with HDR (obviusly High Dynamic Range Images) but do you mean a file format image.hdr? or did you tone mapped a raw image. If it is the second case try using a 16 bit file.

Comment: A 16bit file with hdr format :)

Comment: Oops NO. they are both 32 bits. Maybe that's the reason! Turning to 16 bit will be bad?

Comment: I tried, and it worked. BUT... It looses the HDR effect. That's bad...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when making a lightprobe, the images need to be taken at 90-degrees from each other, not opposite sides of the sphere.  If you take them 180-degrees from each other, the bits you want to replace will exactly overlap each other.

Secondly, you need to "unwrap" each image to a flat mapping that's a full **360** panorama--they aren't half-180-panoramas. The reason you can replace bits is because they're both almost-full panoramas. I'd probably use [the commercial Flexify plugin for Photoshop](http://www.flamingpear.com/flexify.html) to map mirrorball->equirectangular, although maybe the free [Ornament plugin](http://www.flamingpear.com/ornament.html) would work for this. Once you have 360-degree panoramas, you can use Hugin to rotate one of the images in yaw  by 90 degrees, so they'll overlap exactly.

Then, you bring each image in on a separate layer, and using masks, you can combine the bits you want from the two images to eliminate the parts you don't want.

Comment: This is not the answer.
I already have those unwrapped. What i asked is WHY can't i do what you say in your last phrase:
"Then, you bring each image in on a separate layer, and using masks..."
I can't do that, and that's what i asked in my question :-)

Comment: @darkgaze Thanks for the clarification--I was mostly responding to what I saw as ambiguities--I thought you couldn't get the two unwrapped images to align because you didn't say you'd rotated one of them. Maybe reword your question to be more along the lines of "Why can't I create two layers from two separate image files in Photoshop?"

Comment: There you have my question. Shorter and more specific. IT is true, I was a bit confused when I asked it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both images open in different projects:

- On the image you want to copy over another, right-click the image
  layer and choose `Duplicate Layer`. A dialog will appear where you
  can select the document where you want to paste the layer.
- You can try to drag & drop a layer from one project to another, but this doesn't always work.

If you want to open two (or more) images in the same document:

- Select `File` -> `Scripts` -> `Load Files into Stack`.